# golang-grpc : service procedure with 2 variable

Tags: go, grpc-go

I'm new to Golang and GRPC.
I Followed https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/ and have no error.

Next I want to add 'procedure' to that greeter service.

Here is my helloworld. proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";

option go_package = "google.golang.org/grpc/examples/helloworld/helloworld";
option java_multiple_files = true;
option java_package = "io.grpc.examples.helloworld";
option java_outer_classname = "HelloWorldProto";

package helloworld;

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
  // Sends another greeting - anyar
  rpc SayHelloAgain (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
  // Multiply. My try too add new procedure
  rpc Multiply (MultiplyRequest) returns (MultiplyReply) {}
}


// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}

// Request message for 'Multiply'
message MultiplyRequest{
    int32 var1 = 1;
    int32 var2 = 2;
}

// Reply message for 'Multiply'
message MultiplyReply{
    int32 result = 1;
}
```

The protoc run successfully.

here is my greeter_server/main.go

```
// Package main implements a server for Greeter service.
package main

import (
    "context"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"

    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    pb "google.golang.org/grpc/examples/helloworld/helloworld"
)

var (
    port = flag.Int("port", 50051, "The server port")
)

// server is used to implement helloworld.GreeterServer.
type server struct {
    pb.UnimplementedGreeterServer
}

// SayHello implements helloworld.GreeterServer
func (s *server) SayHello(ctx context.Context, in *pb.HelloRequest) (*pb.HelloReply, error) {
    log.Printf("Received: %v", in.GetName())
    return &pb.HelloReply{Message: "Hello " + in.GetName()}, nil
}

func (s *server) SayHelloAgain(ctx context.Context, in *pb.HelloRequest) (*pb.HelloReply, error) {
    log.Printf("Again Received: %v", in.GetName())
    return &pb.HelloReply{Message: "Hello again " + in.GetName()}, nil
}

// Multiply implements helloworld.GreeterServer

func (s *server) Multiply(ctx context.Context, in *pb.MultiplyRequest) (*pb.MultiplyReply, error) {
    log.Printf("Multiply Received: %v and %v", in.GetVar1(), in.GetVar2())
    var myResult = in.GetVar1() * in.GetVar2()
    return &pb.MultiplyReply{Result: myResult}, nil
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", fmt.Sprintf(":%d", *port))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to listen: %v", err)
    }
    s := grpc.NewServer()
    pb.RegisterGreeterServer(s, &server{})
    log.Printf("server listening at %v", lis.Addr())
    if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to serve: %v", err)
    }
}
```

my vscode still not reporting any error.

Now, the client (where the problems occur)

```
// Package main implements a client for Greeter service.
package main

import (
    "context"
    "flag"
    "log"
    "time"

    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/credentials/insecure"
    pb "google.golang.org/grpc/examples/helloworld/helloworld"
)

const (
    defaultName = "world"
)

var (
    addr = flag.String("addr", "localhost:50051", "the address to connect to")
    name = flag.String("name", defaultName, "Name to greet")
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    // Set up a connection to the server.
    conn, err := grpc.Dial(*addr, grpc.WithTransportCredentials(insecure.NewCredentials()))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("did not connect: %v", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    c := pb.NewGreeterClient(conn)

    // Contact the server and print out its response.
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    r, err := c.SayHello(ctx, &pb.HelloRequest{Name: *name})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not greet: %v", err)
    }
    log.Printf("Greeting: %s", r.GetMessage())

    // Say Again
    r, err = c.SayHelloAgain(ctx, &pb.HelloRequest{Name: *name})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not greet: %v", err)
    }
    log.Printf("Greeting: %s", r.GetMessage())

    // Multiply --> Problem
    r, err = c.Multiply(ctx, &pb.MultiplyRequest{Var1: 3, Var2: 4})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("could not Multiply: %v", err)
    }
    log.Printf("Result: %s", r.GetResult())

}
```

For line containing "r, err = c.Multiply(ctx, &pb.MultiplyRequest{Var1: 3, Var2: 4})"
my vscode report :

```
cannot use c.Multiply(ctx, &pb.MultiplyRequest{…}) (value of type *helloworld.MultiplyReply) as *helloworld.HelloReply value in assignment
```

And for line containing "log.Printf("Result: %s", r.GetResult())"
My vscode report error

```
r.GetResult undefined (type *helloworld.HelloReply has no field or method GetResult)
```

kindly please help me to how to fix the problem.
Sincerely
-bino-

Solved by @trock and @mahesh

Comment: You cant use same name `r`. `SayHello*` returns `*pb.HelloReply` and `Multiply` returns `*pb.MultiplyReply`. Just change the variable name `r`.

Comment: It's because of the type mismatch, you are using `r` as result type for both `HelloReply` and `MultiplyReply` you can use new variable ther eand that should fix the issue.

So this should `r, err = c.Multiply(ctx, &pb.MultiplyRequest{Var1: 3, Var2: 4})` become `newr, err := c.Multiply(ctx, &pb.MultiplyRequest{Var1: 3, Var2: 4})` or any other name you want